# Android notification height

Tags: android, android-layout, notifications

I created custom notification with a using layout ( my notification UI created in xml file ).
I can change notification height? ( notification created for android 2.1 )

If I can how?
If I can't, how can I create TextView with a vertical scroll?
what version of android I can change the height of the notification?
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen a non-standard height on the notification. And, thinking about it, it's probably one of those things that can't be changed, for the better. Imagine opening up your notification tray, and the whole thing is taken up by a flashing "YOU ARE THE 100000TH USER!" ad. If you need to display more information, why not create a widget?

Answer (score 2):

As of Jellybean, there are expandable notifications.  See http://developer.android.com/about/versions/jelly-bean.html